# How to link CocoaImageHashing pod with Swift project (dyld: Library not loaded)

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to use the CocoaImageHashing pod from a Swift project so that I can do some perceptual hashing for image duplicate detection.

I setup the workspace following the CocoaPods instructions and attempted to run the default Hello World swift file.

`dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/CocoaImageHashing.framework/Versions/A/CocoaImageHashing
  Referenced from: /Users/sarge/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PHashTest-cdongczzcrynrfclysczwalanrlq/Build/Products/Debug/PHashTest
  Reason: image not found
(lldb)`

My Podfile is:

````
platform :osx, '10.12'
target 'PHashTest' do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'CocoaImageHashing', :git => 'https://github.com/ameingast/cocoaimagehashing.git'```
end
````

I tried commenting out the use_frameworks! line in case this was some kind of dynamic library problem. I then get a build error.

```
Framework not found CocoaImageHashing
```

My **General > Linked Frameworks and Libraries** does include the CocoaImageHashing framework. I see Xcode building files from it during a build.

Is there something I have to do to get the CocoaImageHashing pod to build the dynamic library that Swift expects? Or do I need to not use Swift because CocoaImageHashing has to be included dynamically.

(I'm very unfamiliar with Swift so I don't know what to look for)

Answer (score 0):

You should include the framework at General -> Embedded Binaries as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't seem to have a General -> Embedded Binaries. I'm targeting macOS here. Is Embedded Binaries an iOS thing? Or is there some other way to turn it on?